# Can anyone that knows how to analyze crash/dump files help me figure out what is crashing my pc?

Tags: memory, crash, bsod, gaming, minidumps

I recently built a desktop pc with windows 10 64-bit and everything works fine except for playing certain games. I can play some games like diablo 3 for hours with no problems but other games like xcom 2 and ac syndicate crash my pc to either a bsod or a red screen with no text within the first ten minutes of gameplay. My pc also crashes when I try to bench or stress test my gpu with heaven unigine but doesn't crash when I stress test with furmark.

I reinstalled windows 10 twice, and also tried a clean reinstall of different graphics drivers several times, I'll list other things I tried:

- Ran memtest86+ twice and got to 10 passes both times with no errors
- scanned my hard drive for errors, no errors were found
- sent my gpu to xfx to have it tested, they said they tested it overnight with benchmarks, stress tests and games and it never caused a crash
- I also sent back my psu to seasonic, they sent it back saying it works fine
- I have been talking with 2k (xcom publishers) and we have tried many, many things and nothing has worked.
- I also monitored my temperatures and my gpu temps never reached more than 65 degrees ceclsius when gaming or more than 80 degrees celcius when benchmarking, so it's not an overheating issue
- I was also monitory my ran while playing and I never went over 3.5 GB, so it can't be a memory leak
- I even tried to uninstall my antivirus and play in a clean boot environment and I would still get the same crashes

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7EzkxT5H6uyaVF6X2Y1VzJ0NkU/view?usp=sharing) is a google drive link to my crash/dump files.
All of them are small memory dumps and the most recent one (march 11) is a kernal memory dump. I noticed on my pc that it created two dumps for march 11, one at about 10:30pm and another at 11:20pm, the thing is my pc only cashed at 11:20pm, at 10:30pm I had just turned it on to test it with xcom 2 and see if it would crash.

Here are my pc specs:

```
intel i5-6500  
asrock z170 pro4s  
xfx r9 280x 3gb  
g.skill ripjaws 8gb ddr4 ram (2 x 4gb)  
seasonic 650w gold certified  
western digital 1tb blue
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: windbg will help you determine the cause of the crash

Comment: I have tried to read the files using windbg but I don't understand how to analyze the files and figure it out? Most of the files say crash caused by driver ntoskrnl.exe, when I googled that I found out that it is a windows 10 kernal and it has to do with memory, but I have tested my ram, hard drive and gpu and all of those are working fine, I also tried to increase virtual memory to 12gb and nothing.

Comment: I looked at the newest dump and see a memory corruption (1 bit is flipped). if memtest86+ sows now issues, run CPU-Z and look in the SPD and memory tab and look if the RAM timings match. Also if you see CR is set to 1, change it to 2 in the BIOS/UEFI

Comment: @magicandre1981 The CR rate is set to "2T" and the timings match except for "CAS# Latency (CL)" in the memory tab it shows 15.0 clocks, and the SPD tab shows 4 different values "15.0  16.0  18.0  19.0" for both sticks of ram, should I change anything?

Comment: post pictures, so that I can see what you have.

Comment: @magicandre1981 here is an updated google drive with the pictures of cpu-z, https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7EzkxT5H6uyRkxLVC0zMDhjSWc&usp=sharing                                      and here is the ram I have so you can see the speeds, http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231882

Comment: I have no experience with DDR4 RAM. Strange that the timings differ for the same RAM speed. Set the CAS to 16, 18 and 19 and see if one of the entries fix it.

Comment: have you tried other CAS settings? Are the issues gone?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried that and my pc still crashes, I contacted asrock and they told me to update the bios, I am going to try that next.

Comment: have you tried the BIOS upgrade? Does it work and fixes the issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I updated the bios and was able to play twice for about an hour with no crash, hopefully that fixed the problem.

Comment: ok, watch this a few days and if it fixes it, post it as answer (also which BIOS version you flashed). Maybe other users with the ASRock board have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the bios fixed the issue, I have been playing games for the past few days with no crashes. My motherboard originally had version 1.6 on it, I flashed to version 3.1 and everything works fine now.